# Saving a list to storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, xmlserializer

I'm trying to save a very simple list to storage using `XmlSerializer`

```cs
public class Faves
{
    public Faves(string title, Uri uri)
    {
        Title = title;
        Uri = uri;
    }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Uri Uri { get; set; }
}

public async void savedata()
{
    List<Faves> favs = new List<Faves> { };
    favs.Add(ItemList.SelectedItem as Faves);

    var localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFile file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("newfile", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    try
    {
        using (Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Faves>));
            serializer.Serialize(stream, favs);
        }
    }
    catch
    { }
}
```

But everything I try just results in:

```cs
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in SYSTEM.XML.SERIALIZATION.NI.DLL
```

If I use the faves list in a listbox, everything shows and works fine, I just cant get it to save the list to storage. I have spent days going over every example I can find.

Any help would be great.

EDIT: More to the error

```cs
  cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.
```

Comment: Add a parameter less constructor just as the error says. This would obviously be on the Favs type

Answer (score 2):

Because you have created a custom constructor the default constructor is no longer created by the compiler, therefore you have to create it explicitly.

```
public Faves()
{
}
```